# New to Android, Will this loop upon startup?

Tags: android

I'm new to android dev and I was wondering if, upon startup, will the following code start looping, check the result of connect, vibrate if 1, and then sleep for 5 minutes?

```
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
boolean flag = true;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    while(flag) {
        Handler handler = new Handler(); 
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() { 
            public void run() { 
                String foundblock = connect("blahblahblah"); //will return either 0 or 1
                if (foundblock == "1") {
                    Vibrator v = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
                    long milliseconds = 10;
                    v.vibrate(milliseconds);
                    flag = false;
                }
            } 
        }, 300000); 
    }
```

Comment: 10 milliseconds of vibration...OH YEAH

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, it'll loop.  Don't expect the android process manager to keep it alive for too long though.  It will also result in a ton of runnables being posted, as itll run through the while loop over and over.

Answer (score 1):

This code will be forcefully terminated due to onCreate() not returning within an acceptable time limit. You can start a thread from onCreate() but you can't hang out forever.

Lose the while loop, and just postDelayed(). Your runnable can loop within it (as long as you give yourself a way to be told to terminate it!).

You might change the variable `foundblock` (and the return of your `connect()` function) to boolean or at least an int, since String is overkill for what you're describing and since string checks for equality are not performed with the `==` operator.

Comment: If I move the while loop inside the Runnable, how can I make it sleep for 5 minutes after each iteration?

Answer (score 1):

It will crash as the onCreate has a time limit. If you put the loop in a seperate thread then it will stop the application from crashing.
example:

```
Thread myThread = new Thread(){
        public void run(){
            while(flag) {
                        int foundblock = connect("blahblahblah"); //will return either 0 or 1
                        if (foundblock == 1) {
                        Vibrator v = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
                        long milliseconds = 10;
                        v.vibrate(milliseconds);
                        flag = false;
                        } 
            }
       }
    };
    myThread.start();
```

This definately works, rather than then putting this thread to sleep, just restart it after the time you want to wait has passed by calling myThread.start() again.

Comment: That force closes upon startup.

Comment: I've modified the code, above. Sorry - should have checked it compiled before posting!